# Pyinstaller: "No module named '_curses'" on the generated .exe file

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, curses

This is a simple project where I only have a main.py file which imports curses.
After launching the built .exe I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I tried building to exe with:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import curses --additional-hooks-dir=. main.py
```

I also tried using `windows-curses` instead of `curses`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import windows-curses --additional-hooks-dir=. main.py
```

and I also tried:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w main.py
```

with the same result...

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED.**
Command that worked:

```
pyinstaller -F main.py --hidden-import=windows_curses --hidden-import=pkg_resources
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it turned out the reason was that I had installed the 'missing' library using the pip `-e` editable flag. Removing that flag from my `requirements.txt` file fixed the issue.